# Increase in response time on upgrading to spring boot v2.5.12

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recently I upgraded to spring boot v2.5.12 from 2.3.3.release due to vulnerability issues. But I am seeing increase in response time in v2.5.12 by a factor of 2x+ when I make a cassandra db call. If we look into [changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.5.12) that went in v2.5.12 release, I feel it might be due to spring boot's dependency upgrade to Jackson Bom 2.12.6.20220326 but can't say for sure

Can you pls help me in isolating cause of increase in response time after spring boot version upgrade? After we reverted version upgrade changes, response time came back to normal

Comment: Measure. Use a profiler against both versions, find the hotspots and compare. Just guessing isn't going to help.